# Office JS Add-In

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Is there an event that is triggered whenever a new email is selected within the Outlook Office JS Add-In api? For example, when you pin an Add-In, and replying to multiple emails via the in-line option, the code within the initializer is only called the first.

```
Office.onReady(function(info) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
    // time stamp here
    });
});
```

I confirmed this by printing out the stamp and it stays the same.  I need a certain function to run each time a new email when replying to email via the inline not pop-out is used.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the [addHandlerAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/office.context.mailbox#addhandlerasynceventtype-handler-options-callback) API to subscribe to the **ItemChanged** event.

This is part of the **Pinnable Taskpane** feature. To learn more about this concept in the Outlook Add-ins platform, please refer to this [concept documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/pinnable-taskpane).